# database normalization: 1nf confusion

Tags: mysql, normalization

okay guys so here's my case. our professor told us to normalize this table

```
subjectTbl
|Code   |Description    |Unit|
------------------------------
|e-24   |English 24     |3   |
------------------------------
|m-16   |Mathematics 16 |3   |
------------------------------
|t-3    |Theodbs 3      |4.5 |
```

and my problem is, i'm having trouble figuring out if this table is already in it's first normal form since we only discussed normalization yesterday.

what i've found that the requirment for 1NF is as follows:

•All the key attributes are defined.

•There are no repeating groups in the table.

•All attributes are dependent on the primary key.

if i'm right, Code is partially dependent on Description AND unit, and description is transitively dependent on unit.

any help will be greatly appreciated guys. thanks in advance

Comment: Congratulations. Assuming that really is a full stop and not a comma, then you've passed.

Comment: so the given above is really in it's first normal form?